# Do I really need to specify the file type when using os.rename?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to use the os module for the first time to rename multiple files at once. However, it seems I have to specify the file type. Otherwise, the file can't be opened anymore. It becomes like this:

[image: It becomes like this]

But can I do it without specifying the filetype? How do I do that?

My current code when I don't specify it is this

```
import os

option = input("\nRename files in current directory? Yes or no: ").lower()

if (option == "yes"):
    path = os.getcwd()
else:    
    path = os.chdir(input("\nEnter directory: "))
    
name = input("\nEnter new filename: ")

i = 0
for source in os.listdir(path):
    destination =name + str(i) 
    os.rename(source, destination)
    i += 1
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: yes, if you done specifiy a file type then it doesnt know what to save it as, just use destination + "txt") (for a txt file)

Comment: You need to save the current extension. Now you are specifically removing it, by not adding it again after setting the `destination` name.

Comment: "os.path.splitext" can extract the extension of the current file name so that you can append it to the new file name.

Comment: The extension isn't the file type. You can rename a file from `foo.pdf` to `foo.mp4`, but it won't be a video. The extension is just part of the name. If you want the new name to include a particular extension, then yes, you need to specify it. As Michael mentioned, you can easily find the extension used by the file originally and use that in your code. (Side note: Windows doesn't help users here. By hiding known file extensions out of the box, and by conflating file type and file extension, it's no wonder that its users are often confused on these points.)

Comment: Ohhh I always thought it was called file type haha my bad and it works now, thank you so much!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`os.rename` does not care about extensions (*"file types"*, as you call them), but Windows does. If there is no extension, Windows does not know what the file is.

You can extract the extension of the file before renaming and append it to the new name.

You can use `os.path.splitext` to get the original extension:

```
old_name, extension = os.path.splitext(old_filename)
new_filename = new_name + extension
os.rename(old_filename, new_filename)
```

In your case:

```
for i, source in enumerate(os.listdir(path)):
    old_name, extension = os.path.splitext(source)
    destination = name + str(i) + extension
    os.rename(source, destination)
```

Answer (score -1):

This is about the file extension. The extension is used by Windows to select the application to use for opening that file.

Without an extension, Windows could not select which program to use. But if you open the file with the correct program, you will not have any issue.

Comment: I didn't downvote the answer, but it looks like you did not answer the question.  OP wanted to rename files with an input base name while keeping their extensions unchanged.  Your answer did not address that problem at all.

Comment: Indeed taht was not what he asked. Thanks for the clarification.